# Update panel issue on chrome and Firefox Sharepoint Webpart Page Will Get Full Post back on Dropdown change

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, asp.net

I am using ASP.NET update panel in SharePoint WebParts and I am Having the DropDown With AutoPostBack true firing the Event OnSelectedIndexChanged Page will get Fully refresh on DropDown Change.

Below is the Code Block Which I have Written.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updtPnlSchemeInfo" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlSchemeInfo" runat="server">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDiscountRuleType" Style="width: 340px;" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDiscountRuleType_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlDiscountRuleType" />
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnNextScheme" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: I tried running this code in my environment on firefox and its working as expected. Can you try changing the `Triggers` to `<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlDiscountRuleType" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />` and check either its working or not?

Comment: You are doing it in the SharePoint WebPart?

Comment: Yes, SharePoint farm solution, with Visual Web part.

Comment: Hi @DineshTalekar did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following code? I checked with your code as well and it is also working me for.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="ajaxUp" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTest" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTest_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="Select"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Test" Value="Test"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlTest" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>
```

Code behind file:

```
protected void ddlTest_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtTest.Text = "Changed from ddlTest_SelectedIndexChanged event";
    ajaxUp.Update();
}
```

Comment: Tried With the Same Still doesn't Work :( . It is not getting refresh every time. I will get refresh sometime after two three times DropDown change

Comment: Page is getting full refresh only if I get it idle for some time

Comment: this is normal behavior.